# Load Average runaway

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there any way to chase down lockups and runaway load averages?

Every so often (pretty randomly) I'll get my load average spike up over 5 usually to around 10-15 and sometimes as high as 75 (dual core machine), and cause my system to lock for an indeterminate amount of time.

The only thing I can possibly chase it to is using nVidia fakeraid (RAID-1) with JFS on top of that for my /home partition.

Also I noticed that when my load averages spike, the power management system doesn't step up my processor speed from 1.6 to its maximum 2.13Ghz clock speed (not sure if this makes a huge difference with this problem).

Any ideas?

Comment: My system load gets really high, too, and I don't know why.  Did you have any luck finding a source?

Answer (score -1):

the ubuntu networkmanager daemon is notorious for causing problems with low latency applications, if I recall that is because it randomly uses large amounts of CPU. You could try shutting it down and see if the load spikes go away. `/etc/init.d/networking stop` should shut it down. If you are using ethernet, simply running `dhclient eth0` should suffice to get you on line.

Comment: I typically remove it (albeit it is running right now), and I seem to remember issues still.  Does your standard apt-get purge networkmanager suffice to get rid of it fully?

Comment: Just noticed, I already have network manager removed.